# How can I take the square root of -1 using python?

Tags: python, numpy

When I take the square root of -1 it gives me an error:

> invalid value encountered in sqrt

How do I fix that?

```
from numpy import sqrt
arr = sqrt(-1)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Not sure about numpy but in pure python you can use `cmath.sqrt(-1)`.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but I can't reproduce that issue exactly. I get `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt` on the calculation, then `nan` is printed (which is a `numpy.float64`, to be clear).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the sqrt from the [cmath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) module (part of the standard library)

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Answer (score 34):

To avoid the `invalid value` warning/error, the argument to numpy's `sqrt` function must be complex:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: np.sqrt(-1+0j)
Out[9]: 1j
```

As @AshwiniChaudhary pointed out in a comment, you could also use the `cmath` standard library:

```
In [10]: cmath.sqrt(-1)
Out[10]: 1j
```

Answer (score 21):

I just discovered the convenience function `numpy.emath.sqrt` explained in the [sqrt documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html). I use it as follows:

```
>>> from numpy.emath import sqrt as csqrt
>>> csqrt(-1)
1j
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest addendum to the [Numpy Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.emath.sqrt.html#numpy.emath.sqrt) here, adds the command `numpy.emath.sqrt` which returns the complex numbers when the negative numbers are fed to the square root sign in a operation.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of -1 is not a real number, but rather an imaginary number. IEEE 754 does not have a way of representing imaginary numbers.

numpy has support for complex numbers. I suggest you use that: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: My guess is that @marriam is already using numpy, because `np.sqrt(-1)` results in the `invalid value encountered...` warning, while `math.sqrt(-1)` results in `ValueError: math domain error`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Either way, an appreciation of what complex numbers are will help her.

Answer (score 0):

Others have probably suggested more desirable methods, but just to add to the conversation, you could always multiply any number less than 0 (the value you want the sqrt of, -1 in this case) by -1, then take the sqrt of that. Just know then that your result is imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by specifying the `dtype` as complex in numpy's `sqrt` function

```
from numpy import sqrt
arr = sqrt(-1, dtype=np.complex128)
print(arr)
```