# multiply matrix by i in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numbers

I am using numpy and am trying the following computation:

```
efield = p+ (np.sqrt(-1))*q       #(where p and q are arrays)
```

however I get the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Polarization E Feild.py", line 115
    efield = p+ (np.sqrt(-1))*q
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Polarization E Feild.py", line 115, in <module>
    efield = p+ (np.sqrt(-1))*q
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How is i (square root of -1) used in numpy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766774/how-can-i-take-the-square-root-of-1-using-python/17767080#17767080

Comment: Why not write `efield = p + 1j*q`?