# sqrt of negative sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, complex-numbers, sqrt

How can I find `sqrt` of sparse matrix containing negative numbers in python? `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sqrt` and `numpy.sqrt` doesn't work for negative numbers. I also tried to use `cmath.sqrt(mat_name.data)`. But it's not working also.

Comment: Are you looking for the square root of each individual number in the matrix, or a matrix square root in the sense of matrix multiplication?

Comment: individual numbers of a matrix

Answer (score 1):

`from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt` works to find `sqrt` of sparse matrix with negative numbers. Found the answer here [How can I take the square root of -1 using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766774/how-can-i-take-the-square-root-of-1-using-python) from @David Zwicker